# Set backcolor of a Gridview control, when it is enabled or disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, page-lifecycle

In my gridview controls are enabled or disabled depending on user roles. I want to change the background color to yellow for enabled controls. I have tried to do it in `RowCreated` as below but all the cells are enabled at that time.

```
protected void begv_OrderDetail_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
     {
          if (cell.Enabled == true)
          {
          }
          else
          {
             //Never enters this area
          }

     }
}
```

Here is an example field in my gridview where I enable or disable the controls.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ReasonCode" SortExpression="ReasonCode">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ToolTip="ReasonCode" runat="server" Text="RC"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ReasonCode" onchange="disableNextStatusButtons()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReasonCode") %>'
                Enabled='<%# (Roles.IsUserInRole("İhracat Uzmanı") && Session["Status"].ToString()=="3") %>'
                Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Where are you enabling and disabling the controls?

Comment: @nunespascal , I have edited my question and add a little piece of my code from my gridview, where you can see the enabled option.

Comment: you can use the same syntax to set the color too. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `BackColor` too in using the data binding syntax

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ReasonCode" 
             onchange="disableNextStatusButtons()" 
             runat="server"
             Text='<%# Bind("ReasonCode") %>'
             Enabled='<%# (Roles.IsUserInRole("İhracat Uzmanı") && Session["Status"].ToString()=="3") %>'
             BackColor='<%# (Roles.IsUserInRole("İhracat Uzmanı") && Session["Status"].ToString()=="3") ? System.Drawing.Color.Red: System.Drawing.Color.Green %>'
             Width="40px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

A little ugly, but will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the following step

1. check the user role on RowDatabound
2. On RowDatabound change the color of the row

   ```
   protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           //check role
            if (condition)
              e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else
              e.Row.BackColor = Color.Green;  
           //or set you individual control background 
            //get any control
             var chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkb");
            //set background
             chk.BackColor = Color.Red;//etc
        }
   }
   ```

You can set css dynamically to the textbox `CssClass="yourcss"`

```
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ReasonCode" onchange="disableNextStatusButtons()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReasonCode") %>'
                Enabled='<%# (Roles.IsUserInRole("İhracat Uzmanı") && Session["Status"].ToString()=="3") %>'
                CssClass='<%# (Roles.IsUserInRole("İhracat Uzmanı") && Session["Status"].ToString()=="NormalCss").ToString()=="true"?"yellowcss":"othercss"  %>'
                Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I have that in my mind, but this doubles the conditions where I have to check the roles, and I wouldn't like to do like that.

Comment: Because I use roles to make the control enabled or disabled, (see edited part in my question), so I don't want to use the same condition when I change the color of the same control, because if a condition changes, then I have to both change the place which enables and disables, and the place which you indicated above.

Comment: @HOY I have updated my answer. You can create two css classes and set it dynamically as you are enabling and disabling the controls.

Answer (score 0):

> Try it in RowDataBound event of the Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataBound event to iterate thru all cells and update the bg.